# Text input placeholder returning something it is not supposed to

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

I don't know why it is doing this. It has never done it before

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="query" placeholder="something"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      query: String,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

And the input looks like this when the site loads

[image: text input]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try closing the script tag properly `</script>` not `<script/>`. If that's not it then provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` is an object constructor in JavaScript.

- The Vue data object needs to return an object.
- Each key should initialize a value or `undefined`/`null`
- Reactive Vue data types are infered. See [this](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-options-api) on types in Vue.

Initialize the value as a empty string, like this:

```json
{
    query: ""
}
```

or `undefined` like this

```json
{
    query: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of solution. Changed

```
query: String
```

to

```
query: ""
```